# Shell Script for FTP not loggin in

Tags: shell, ftp

hey all i have ready the numerous posts about this type of issue but none of the suggestions have resolved my issue. Maybe i am missing something? what i am trying to do is ftp files from remote server "A" and save them to the local webserver and i plan on running this script through cron as such

My Cron:

```
* 1 * * * ./public/xfer.sh > ./public/xferlog.log
```

My Script:

```
HOST='255.255.255.255'
USER='myadminuser'
PASSWD='supersecretpassword'

ftp -n -v -i $HOST<<EOF
quote USER $USER $PASSWD
lcd /usr/www/xxxx/public/svss/cq
ascii
cd svss
get pbsvss.htm
binary
close
EOF
```

Gives me these errors ..

```
./xfer.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
./xfer.sh: line 14: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (w')ted `END_SCRIPT
 (255.255.255.255)..255.255.255
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
331 Password required for myadminuser .
530 User cannot log in.
usage: lcd local-directory
200 Type set to A.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
 remote: pbsvss.htm
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp: bind: Address already in use
200 Type set to I.
221 Goodbye.
?Invalid command
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not also requiring a domain name given that it's a Windows system you're logging in to? Something like `somedomain/myadminuser`

Comment: Slightly off topic: For transferring files via FTP, I find it much easier to use the `ncftp` collection of utilities than to use ftp directly.

Comment: i'm sure i don't need a domain, as i can copy and paste each line and it work fine. As for the ncftp, unfortunately i'm on a shared hosting system and do not have access to install any other apps/programs. i do have ssh access and this is where i am testing the code

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i decided to use wget to do this instead.

now all i have to do is the following 1 line of code,

```
wget -P /path/to/save/to/ -nH --cut-dirs=1 -m ftp://user:pass@ip.or.hostname/directory/
```

Comment: Just as a note, this puts the password on the command line and anyone user with a shell on the system can use `ps` to view your complete command line.  In many situations, that could be a security concern.

Comment: More: A quick look at the man page shows that `wget` supports `~/.wgetrc` (or `~/.netrc`) so that passwords can be stored relatively securely.

Answer (score 0):

what i do to fix the security issue is never pass raw passwords into the script.

something like this (obviously i take further steps but this is the basics for it)

in shell i do,

```
echo -n 'mysecretpass' | base64
c2NvdHRsaW51eC5jb20gcm9ja3MK
```

then in the script i just use the output in the cmdline

```
$pass = c2NvdHRsaW51eC5jb20gcm9ja3MK | base64 --decode
```